# Is the number of real roots of a polynomial locally constant?

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Let
$$p(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + \cdots + a_n x^n \in \mathbb{R}[x]$$
be a polynomial with real coefficients. Suppose that $f$ has no repeated *real* root. (It may have repeated complex roots, but we ignore those.)

**Question:** Is it true that if we perturbe the coefficients $a_i$ slightly, then the number of real roots of $p(x)$ will remain the same?

In more precise language, the claim would be that there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that if $b_i \in \mathbb{R}$ satisfy $|b_i - a_i| < \epsilon$ for all $i$ then the number of real roots of
$$q(x) = b_0 + b_1 x + \cdots + b_n x^n$$
is equal to the number of real roots of $p(x)$.

Comment: Yes (think of it graphically).

Comment: What about $p=x^2$, having two real roots (counted with multiplicity), which we perturb slightly to $q=x^2+\epsilon$, which has no real roots.

Comment: @AndrewHubery The question specifically says that the function has no repeated real roots, which is not true of $x^2$.

Comment: A small technicality but I think you need to have that $a_n\neq 0$ as a a condition